# Chrome Extension: Invalid manifest on Linux and MacOS with installs from store

Tags: javascript, linux, macos, google-chrome-extension

I've just tried publishing my first extension on the chrome web store, and I get the error you can see on the post's title when trying to install it from the store page. I can instally fine on Windows (chrome, edge and brave work fine), but MacOS and Linux fail with and error saying "invalid manifest".

The manifest is as follows:

```js
{
    "name":"Layfy",
    "version":"0.1.2",
    "description":"Control your spotify playback in a popup window",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup":"index.html"
    },
    "options_ui": {
        "page":"options.html",
        "open_in_tab":false
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts":["background.js"],
        "persistent":false
    },
    "commands": {
        "toggle_play_pause": {
            "description":"Pause/Resume playback",
            "suggested_key": {
                "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
            }
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icons/16.png",
        "48": "icons/icons/48.png",
        "128": "icons/icons/128.png"
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? I have no idea wha's wrong with it.

Comment: I guess it wants you to specify all platforms in `suggested_key`.

Comment: it worked!! Thank you so much @wOxxOm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer here for better visibility:

based on the comment from @wOxxOm, I removed the commands object (it was there just as a test feature anyway). That appeared to have solved the issue.
It seems that you cannot specify only one system keybind, otherwise it will block installing the extension on other platforms.